# Calico etcd has no key named calico

Tags: kubernetes, etcd, calico

I have a 2 node kubernetes cluster with calico networking. All the pods are up and running.

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                       READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE

kube-system   calico-etcd-94466                          1/1       Running   0          21h
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-5fdcfdbdf7-xsjxb   1/1       Running   0          14d
kube-system   calico-node-hmnf5                          2/2       Running   0          14d
kube-system   calico-node-vmmmk                          2/2       Running   0          14d
kube-system   coredns-78fcdf6894-dlqg6                   1/1       Running   0          14d
kube-system   coredns-78fcdf6894-zwrd6                   1/1       Running   0          14d
kube-system   etcd-kube-master-01                        1/1       Running   0          14d
kube-system   kube-apiserver-kube-master-01              1/1       Running   0          14d
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-kube-master-01     1/1       Running   0          14d
kube-system   kube-proxy-nxfht                           1/1       Running   0          14d
kube-system   kube-proxy-qnn45                           1/1       Running   0          14d
kube-system   kube-scheduler-kube-master-01              1/1       Running   0          14d
```

I wanted to query calico-etcd using etcdctl, but I get the following error.

```
# etcdctl --debug --endpoints "http://10.142.137.11:6666" get calico
start to sync cluster using endpoints(http://10.142.137.11:6666)
cURL Command: curl -X GET http://10.142.137.11:6666/v2/members
got endpoints(http://10.142.137.11:6666) after sync
Cluster-Endpoints: http://10.142.137.11:6666
cURL Command: curl -X GET http://10.142.137.11:6666/v2/keys/calico?quorum=false&recursive=false&sorted=false
Error:  100: Key not found (/calico) [4]
```

Any pointers on why I get this error?

Comment: Do etcdctl queries for other resources work?

Comment: Can you try getting all keys from etcd and add output?
`ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl get / --prefix --keys-only`

Comment: Could you explain please what was the problem :)? I would really appreciate if you can up vote my comment if I helped ^_^

Comment: I think the API version is 2 by default. The output for the above command is `/calico/ipam/v2/assignment/ipv4/block/192.168.201.64-26 /calico/ipam/v2/assignment/ipv4/block/192.168.212.128-26 /calico/ipam/v2/handle/k8s-pod-}network.1346353eeb0bdd5a5cbbb965105990076a6809a541633466b4928e230c67f834 `

But when I execute the below command I don't see any output: 
`etcdctl --endpoints "10.142.137.11:6666"; get /calico/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JakubBujny mentioned, `ETCDCTL_API=3` should be set to get the appropriate result.

Comment: I had to do:
`etcdctl get /calico/ipam/v2/assignment/ipv4/block/192.168.201.64-26 --prefix`
to make it work